# How to multiply two lookup column values in workflow - sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have to create a work flow which should multiply two list look-up column values into other column. Can anybody provide me any help or sample reference on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [SharePoint](http://www.dshift.com/our-solutions/dshift-migrator-for-sharepoint-2013/) Designer 2013 you have the "Do Calculation" action which takes two variables (your two lookup values), makes a calculation (minus, plus, multiplied etc) and outputs the result to a new variable. Then you can use this variable for whatever you want to do, send it in an e-mail, update a list item or perhaps just log it in the workflow history.